# Brewing with Pico C results in way too much yeast flavor

Tags: beer

When I brew according to the instructions by the picobrew in my pico C the resulting beer has way too much yeast flavor. I already had 3 batches and all of them have this problem.

**Edit:**
After getting more details I noticed their manual changed.

Here is old version of the manual (the one I actually followed for my brews):
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8oEUsdj4NpSWFdvYjIyODY0bUE/view?usp=sharing

Here is new one: https://picobrew.com/About/Manual_PicoC.cshtml

Fermentation step actually now is different. (page 60 step 2)

I guess I should try with new instructions and see if it's any better (they do say to pitch only half of packet now, instead of full. Also they no longer recommend to aerate the wort).

My original question was:
How to minimize the yeast flavor?

I tried tasting beer 1 month after bottling, 2 months, 3 months. It's always way too much yeast flavor.

Comment: What is the question you are wanting to ask, this is currently just a statement. Would you like to know how to avoid this? What could contribute to this? Is there a way to remove this? please see this for more information: https://www.stackoverflow.help/support/solutions/articles/36000042856-asking-a-question

Comment: Please edit your question to add a question, like: "How to minimise the yeast flavor?" or "What causes the yeast flavor?"  Also add more details, like how long after did you taste your beer.

Comment: please share more information about your process....how its kegged or bottled...etc.

Comment: @jsolarski From what I can see, the Pico C has its own mini keg that is part of the system. Not sure if you can dispense directly from it though...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know a fair amount about the Pico C. My father has one and I've brewed with it a couple of times. What I find is that when you bottle from the little keg you ferment in, too much yeast and other junk gets into the bottles or dispensing keg resulting in a beer with a lot of sediment.

Two suggestions.

1. After fermentation, rack it to a 1 gallon glass bottle before you put in drinking bottles. This will help settle the yeast a bit more.
2. Use some gelatin. Gelatin will settle out most of the yeast, resulting in a cleaner tasting product.

I think Pico rushes the bottling process in their instructions, not allowing the yeast to settle out so taking time for the beer to clear for a day or two after most of the fermentation is done will result in clearer beer.

Comment: Maybe add a link to instructions on how to use gelatin.

Answer (score 2):

I've been talking to Picobrew about this for years.  Don't use the whole yeast pack.  That's enough for 5 gallons.  1/2-1 tsp. of the yeast is plenty.

Comment: Denny, I know some people there. I might be able to bug them about it. It does seem like overkill...

Comment: Sure, if you want to, but they'll tell you the same thing.